# How to change calls to localhost into external api calls when deploying app to Heroku?

Tags: reactjs

I finished my app and want to deploy it to Heroku. I've got calls to api (on the local machine) that looks like this

```js
  const isDeleted = await request(
      "DELETE",
      `/api/me/posts/${postId}`
    );
```

In develpoment they were proxied in `package.json` like this

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
```

### How can I change that proxy to external api url?

I've found solution that suggest creating a file with constants and exporting `url` conditionally, sth like this:

```
exports = isProduction ? 'api/production' : 'http://localhost:300'
```

And then prefixing all my calls with that const, but it does not feel right and I think there is a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku has its own env variables. They are called config vars. [See here.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Even though they are Heroku envs, they still have to be prefixed with `REACT_APP`. Otherwise React will not pick them up.

I prefixed all my calls with `REACT_APP_API` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In ReactJs, you can use environment variable to production and development server differently.

Create .env file and .env.production in root directory of projects.

1. It is necessary to use REACT_APP_{Your custom variable name} syntax to pick up by react server.

### .env file

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=https://localhost/
```

### .env.production

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=https://online-exam-mern.herokuapp.com/
```

### JS

```
const response = await fetch(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}admin/auth/login`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          password
        })
      }
    );
```

The react will automatically pick .env.production file variable when you build your projects using npm run build, whereas during development it will use variable from .env file

Comment: I tried this before and it did not work, I'm afraid. But I found a solution and posted it.